# Apache Camel with RabbitMQ - 2.22.1 version connection issue

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, apache-camel

When i upgrade my camel version from 2.14 to 2.22.1 and try to connect to RabbitMQ, i get an connection error

```
 .to("rabbitmq:exchangeName?addresses=${addresses}&exchangeType=topic&autoDelete=false&durable=true&username=${rabbitUserName}&password=${rabbitPassWord}&vhost=${vinHost}&queue=***")
```

I get an connection refused error to rabbitMQ

```
[AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672] ERROR com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler - An unexpected connection driver error occured
```

Comment: Are there more logs to look at? Is the DEBUG level enabled?

Comment: Ya i can add the logs.

Comment: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateProducerException: Failed to create Producer for endpoint:  rabbitmq://***?addresses=localhost&autoDelete=false&durable=true&exchangeType=topic&password=xxxxxx&queue=***&username=***&vhost=***. Reason: java.io.IOException

Comment: @Boris basically it was not able to establish an connection to RabbitMQ. This issue is after we migrated camel to latest version

Comment: Trying to narrow down the issue search. Have you tried to upgrade Apache Camel first to version 2.15, then 2.16, then 2.17 and so on? This would allow us to find the first version which fails and check the corresponding release notes for any clues.

Comment: ok @Boris. I can try this

Comment: @Boris. I tried all versions. The issue seems to be there from 2.15.1 There seems to be an warning from WARN com.rabbitmq.client.TrustEverythingTrustManager and then there is an connection refused exception

Comment: Please add to the question the section of the POM file with a camel dependency. Also, please, add information on the version of Spring Boot.